# Dynamically added buttons covering each other in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS app (my first - I've been a .NET developer for a very long time).

I'm setting up a dynamically added button - everything works great, except the buttons I'm trying to create are covering each other.

Any thoughts on how to dynamically add buttons and change their positions? (In ASP.NET I'd add a placeholder and controls...but in iOS, that's not an option)

Code:

```
UIButton btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn addTarget: self action:@selector(loadQuestion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside;
[btn setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(350.0,750.0,160.0,40.0);
[self.view addSubView:btn];
```

Comment: Are you button frames' different, or you use btn.frame = CGRectMake(350.0,750.0,160.0,40.0); for all of them ? If so, then that is the reason, because basically, each button will have the same position on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use same **X-cordinates** for all buttons. See the below code

```
-(void)addSixButtons{

  float xCord = 5.0;

   for(int itemIndex = 1; itemIndex < 7; itemIndex++){

     UIButton myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
     [myButton addTarget: self action:@selector(loadQuestion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside;
     [myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xCord,750.0,160.0,40.0);
     myButton.tag = itemIndex;
     [self.view addSubView:myButton];

     xCord += 165.0;
   }
}

-(void)loadQuestion:(id)sender{

   UIButton *btnClicked = (UIButton *)sender;

  switch(btnClicked.tag){

       case1:
        //clicked first button
        break;

      case2:
       //clicked second button
       break;

     default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, issue with your code is that you are specifying same frame for the buttons `CGRectMake(350.0,750.0,160.0,40.0)`

you need to change the x position of the button if you want them to align horizontally and can change y posyion if you want to align them vertically.

In iPhone, positions are specified by frame `CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)`. So, specify different x and y values as per reuirement and can also increment that values if you are using loops.